# SQL command using parameters syntax error

Tags: sql

Hi i am new to sql and c# queries. I am using a select statement and puttin @ parameters in using SQL.

```
string cmd = "select (FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country, Username) values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @City, @PostalCode, @Country, @Username) from [Customer];";
```

It doesnt like my sql can anyone tell me why? it says incorrect syntax but i can not spot where?

Thanks
Dom

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT` statement is used to select data from a database.

If you want to retrieve data you don' t have to add the values keyword:

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

With your query:

```
string cmd = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PostalCode, 
              Country, Username FROM Customer;";
```

In case you wanted to retrieve data with the parameters this is the syntax:

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value;
```

With your query:

```
string cmd = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PostalCode, 
              Country, Username FROM Customer WHERE FirstName=@FirstName AND
              LastName=@LastName AND Address=@Address AND City=@City AND
              PostalCode=@PostalCode AND Country=@Country AND Username=@Username;";
```

Altough this is not really correct because you can just check for the id you set on the customer table.

```
string cmd = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, City, PostalCode, 
                  Country, Username FROM Customer WHERE *yourID*=*@yourID*;";
```

You can have a try here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link, you should be using a SELECT INTO statement.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

```
SELECT column_name(s)
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```